# How to get the name field given some conditions in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I have an excel table like this

```
ID, Age, Gender, Name
1, 10,1, 'John'
2, 12,0, 'Marry'
3, 20, 1, 'Peter'
```

Note that, I cannot paste the excel table here, so assume it likes above. Given input is ID, Age, and gender, How to get the name field using python? Thanks
For example, id=2, age=12, gender=0 then output is 'Marry'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xlrd` to read in datas from `.xls` file and use `pandas` to store datas and select:

```
import pandas as pd
from xlrd import open_workbook

#Read datas from .xls file
workbook = open_workbook('data.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
data = []
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    data.append([])
    for col in range(sheet.ncols):
        value = sheet.cell(row,col).value
        if isinstance(value,float):
            value = str(int(value))
        data[-1].append(value)

#Covert datas to DataFrame with column index
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:],columns=data[0],dtype=str)

#Input the select values
ID,age,gender = input('Input ID, age and gender splitted by comma.\n').split(',')

#Select the result and output
name = df.loc[(df['ID'] == ID) &
              (df['Age'] == age) &
              (df['Gender'] == gender)]['Name'].values[0]
print(name)
```

Data in `data.xls` is as your given data.

Input:

> 2,12,0

Output:

> Marry